# Intellij custom folding doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using intellij in my Java project, but it seem that the custom folding doesn't work:

```
        //<editor-fold desc="Description">
        for (int i = idx; i < split.length; i++)
            xmlString += " " + split[i];
        //</editor-fold>
```

The IDE doesn't generate any foldings for the above code block.

Comment: A few questions: 1) What version of IntelliJ IDEA are you running? 2) I assume the above example is Java? 3) When you say "The IDE doesn't generate any foldings", do you mean a) you are not getting the little minus signs in the gutter; or b) the region is not collapsed by default?

Comment: I am using the newest version of Intellij. And I mean I am not getting any little minus signs in the gutter

Answer (score 1):

Try to create custom foldings by shortcut for first time:

1. Select the code fragment of interest,
2. Press `Ctrl+Alt+T`,
3. Select the folding comments to be used.

For some reason when I pasted example from JetBrains website it didn`t work, but after that every folding works corectly.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did exactly like what you said, but it didn't work at all. But in other projects this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `//region xyz` and `//endregion`. This is what I use all the time.

e.g., a silly unit test with folding regions:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    //region Setup
    MyDependency dep = EasyMock.mock("dep", MyDependency.class);
    MyThing thing = new MyThing(dep);
    //endregion

    //region Expectations
    expect(dep.trySomething()).andReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    EasyMock.replay(dep);
    //endRegion

    //region Execution, Assertion, and Verification
    ThingStatus status = thing.doIt();
    Assert.assertEquals("doIt was successful", ThingStatus.OK, status);
    EasyMock.verify(dep);
    //endregion
}
```

The regions of code between `region` and `endregion` will be foldable. While folded, they will be aliased with the descriptive text you provide on the `region` line.

It's a bit more manual than keyboard shortcuts, but this has never failed for me.